# Importing modules in Django (newbie)

Tags: python, django

I'm new to both Python and Django and am struggling with what I'm sure is a very simple thing. I'm using PyCharm as my ide and am attempting to follow quickstart guide [here][1]. I setup a virtual env as per the tutorial.

The project is "DjangoProjectApp" and the app is "Lunch"

With the files shown below and a browser pointed to `http://localhost:8000/admin/` I get the error:

```
ImportError at /admin/
No module named 'DjangoProjects.Lunch'
```

But if I comment out the second url route in urls.py then it works. What is the correct way for me to import this module? Thanks.

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'DjangoProjects.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^lunch/$', 'DjangoProjects.Lunch.views.index')
)
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response


def index(request):
    return render_to_response('index.html')
```

index.html

```
hello world!
```

settings.py

```
"""
Django settings for DjangoProjects project.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/
"""

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'd^d9v4j(1maq-&_8^a+kgicmagxwbv*9m$!2st&vqz$5_h$441'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'Lunch',
    'django.contrib.admin',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'DjangoProjects.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'DjangoProjects.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Comment: Try replacing `DjangoProjects.Lunch.views.index` with `Lunch.views.index`.

Comment: Thanks. That did fix module-not-found error. I think the reason I originally added the fully qualified name was that, without it, it throws another error saying TemplateDoesNotExist. "Index" is definitely defined in views.py so do you know why it can't find it?

Comment: Check your [TEMPLATE_DIRS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#template-dirs) setting.

Comment: Woot! That did it. Gosh, would've been nice if they'd mentioned that in the tutorial. Thanks.

Comment: Well, there is some info about it in the tutorial, see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial03/#write-views-that-actually-do-something).

Comment: I meant the JetBrains tutorial I was following [here](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/quickstart/django_guide.html). But thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

Replace that line with :

```
url(r'^lunch/$', 'Lunch.views.index')
```

There is no need to specify the name of the project. You should start from the app name.

Also, make sure `Lunch` is in the `INSTALLED_APPS` in the settings file.